# Django Templatetag, List index out of range

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I got a simple templatetag which returns a random fact. When there are no facts in the database, I'm getting an exception value **list index out of range**. I wrapped the query set with *try, except** and also checking if there is a fact in the template. You can see the code below:

fact.py

```
# template tag
from django import template
from facts.models import Fact
register = template.Library()


def random_fact():
    try:
        fact = Fact.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    except Fact.DoesNotExist:
        fact = None

    return {'fact': fact}
register.inclusion_tag('facts/fact.html')(random_fact)
```

fact.html

```
<!-- Random Fact Start -->
<div class="panel panel-default sidebar">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Did you know?</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        {% if fact %}
            <p class="text-left">{{ fact.fact }}</p>
            <p class="text-right"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <i><a href="{{ fact.website }}" target="_blank">{{ fact.author }}</a></i></p>
        {% else %}
            <p class="text-left">There are currently no studying tips!</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Random Fact End -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def random_fact():
    fact = Fact.objects.order_by('?').first()
    return {'fact': fact}
```

Comment: This is definitely nicer.

Comment: What does `first()` exactly?

Comment: @ManolisC. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first.

Comment: It's exactly first object (if exist) otherwise is `None`.

Comment: Oh ok! I get it now(that.. otherwise is None is doing all the work I need!)! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Fact.objects.order_by('?')` expression doesn't throw `DoesNotExist` in case of nothing found - it becomes an empty list. Getting 0-th item on an empty list throws [`IndexError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IndexError), catch it:

```
def random_fact():
    try:
        fact = Fact.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    except IndexError:
        fact = None
```

Comment: Yes! That worked! Can you explain what's the difference between `DoesNotExist` and `IndedError`? I got another templatetag that works with `DoesNotExist`!

Comment: So if I had a query set with **get** or **filter** I had to use `DoesNotExist`. Right? Not that I'm getting a list, I have to use `IndexError`?

Comment: @ManolisC. `get` would throw `DoesNotExist`, `filter` would not. Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) for more info.

Comment: Ok thank you! By the way, now I don't know which answer to select as correct as both are!

Comment: @ManolisC. Omid Raha's answer is definitely better and more pythonic.

Comment: Just to check, in this line `events = Event.objects.filter(module_id__in=modules, date__gte=now).order_by('date')[:3]` what should I use? **DoesNotExist**? It doesn't allow me to use **IndexError**.

Comment: @ManolisC. in this case `events` would become an empty list `[]`, no exception.